# mklink not installed on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I just installed Windows 7 Pro, and I'm configuring it to my preferences. I go to set up a symbolic link (since it supports symlinks).

But I don't seem to have the `mklink` program in `C:\Windows\system32`.

In administrator mode in Powershell:

```
PS C:\> mklink
The term 'mklink' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spel
ling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:7
+ mklink <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mklink:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I can't find that file under `%WINDIR%` either, but running `mklink` on my side just works. I guess it's a built in system command. Does it say `mklink` is not a recognized command or something?

Comment: A similar question was asked over at SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894430/powershell-hard-and-soft-links for more information and workarounds.

Comment: @kez: Hunh...didn't think SO was the best place to ask this. ::shrug::

Comment: PowerShell will give this error, but Command Prompt works.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`mklink` is not a standalone tool – it is a built-in command in the Cmd.exe interpreter. The only way to run it externally is through `cmd /c` (similar to `sh -c` on Linux):

```
cmd /c mklink arguments
```

However, PowerShell itself supports creating [various link types](https://superuser.com/a/1375913/1686) using the `New-Item` cmdlet, although it is not a full replacement (as it does not support creating *relative* symlinks).

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink|Junction|HardLink -Name Foo -Target Bar
```

Comment: Above line doesn't work in cmd on win7, though opening a cmd and then mklink works.

Comment: this works also on Windows 10 Pro

Comment: `alias mklink='cmd //c mklink'` for Git Bash; https://stackoverflow.com/a/21907301/3821804

Answer (score 17):

The solution is that mklink is a builtin on cmd.exe. Powershell therefore cannot directly access it.

Negative kudos to whoever thought that one up.

Answer (score 9):

PowerShell is not a complete replacement for CMD.  Many CMD functions do not work in PS.  Switch to CMD to run mklink

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. Pretty frustrating though.