# How do you create a new symlink in windows 10 using powershell (not mklink.exe)?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

If there's docs on it, I'll take that. Any web searches for "symlink" "symbolic link" "windows [10]" "powershell" returns everything except the base command.

Even the powershell docs site returns nothing. Is this not possible?

Comment: Why don’t you want to use mklink you can call it from a PowerShell prompt and/or script

Comment: Please see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/feedback_symbolic

Comment: @Epoxy Thank you. *Fun Fact:* using the search box on the top level of that site returns "No results" when searching for `sym`. In other words, you can't find it if you don't know where it is.

Comment: You are quite welcome! :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

1. Start powershell as admin
2. You need to know 1) the `path to target` of the link 2) `path to location` where you want the link 3) `the name` you want to use to refer to the link.
3. `PS C:\> new-item -itemtype symboliclink -path <path to location> -name <the name> -value <path to target>`

Example: If you're in c:\drivers\AMD and you want to link in f:\driver\olddrivers, then you would go

`PS C:\> new-item -itemtype symboliclink -path . -name OldDrivers -value f:\driver\olddrivers`

And wind up with a symlink path of c:\driver\AMD\OldDrivers

Comment: That's because `mklink` is a specific tool for a specific purpose. Powershell `New-Item` is a very general tool. It can do much more than create directories and symlinks.

Comment: perfect! for those who are wondering, this also works for creating symbolic links to directories ... `PS C:\Users\mcoog> New-Item -itemtype symboliclink -path . -name .vim -value C:\Users\mcoog\Dropbox\.vim`

Comment: FYI, ItemType SymbolicLink was added in PowerShell 5.0

Comment: @monsto you could argue that tools should be very specific rathen than broad in usage

Answer (score 59):

Use the `New-Item` cmdlet and specify the appropriate `ItemType` of `SymbolicLink`, `HardLink`, or `Junction`. Note that these are only available from PowerShell 5.1 or newer.

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| mklink syntax         | PowerShell equivalent                                     |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| mklink Link Target    | New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Name Link -Target Target |
| mklink /D Link Target | New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Name Link -Target Target |
| mklink /H Link Target | New-Item -ItemType HardLink -Name Link -Target Target     |
| mklink /J Link Target | New-Item -ItemType Junction -Name Link -Target Target     |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

- `mklink` reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink
- `New-Item` reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: note: in my tests, `-Name` takes a **file name**, not a file path, replace by `-Path` to give a file path

Comment: Very useful. Thanks.