# Is there a way to use Linux-like symlinks on a Windows computer, referring to a location on another computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, symbolic-link, drive-letter, subst

My application is writing logs to a directory, which is hardcoded "Logs" and is present under the runtime directory of my application.
Today, a customer asked me if it was possible to have those logs on another place (on another computer).

As a first test, I tried to create a symlink:

1. I stopped the application.
2. I removed the "Logs" directory.
3. Using a WSL on my computer, I created a symlink, something like `ln -s /mnt/c/Temp_Folder/TestLog/  /mnt/c/<Application>/Logs`.
4. I started up my application.

I did not see any logs appearing in the directory `C:\Temp_Folder\TestLog\`.

I see different reasons:

- Either it's a complete stupid idea to try to use Linux technology on a Windows computer.
- Either it might work, but some extra things need to be taken into account.

I hope it's the second choice, but in that case, what things do I need to take into account?

**Edit after [Harry](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc)'s answer:**
Why use WSL's `ln -s` if you can use Windows technology, like `mklink`? :-)

I like the idea, but unfortunately it seems not to be working, as you can see from the following experiments:

```
C:\<Runtime_Dir>mklink /D Logs E:\TestLog\
=> result:
29/03/2024  08:21    <SYMLINKD>     Logs [E:\TestLog\]
```

=> So, indeed, the `Logs` directory symlink is created, but when I launch my application, it seems not to write any logs anymore (I see them being created in a console window, but they are not written down in a file).

Some other experiments: (I remember something about a junction from before, but the details have slipped my mind)

```
C:\<Runtime_Dir>mklink /D /J Logs E:\TestLog\
Local volumes are required to complete the operation.
```

```
C:\<Runtime_Dir>mklink /D /H Logs E:\TestLog\
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

```
C:\<Runtime_Dir>mklink /J Logs E:\TestLog\
Local volumes are required to complete the operation.
```

**Edit2 after some more experiments:**
It seems not to work, while referring to another drive, but it does seem to work when I refer to another directory on the same computer, as you can see here:

```
C:\<Runtime_Dir>mklink /D Logs C:\Temp_Folder\TestLog\
symbolic link created for Logs <<===>> C:\Temp_Folder\TestLog\

C:\<Runtime_Dir>mklink /D /J Logs C:\Temp_Folder\TestLog\
Junction created for Logs <<===>> C:\Temp_Folder\TestLog\
```

I can confirm that, in both cases, the logs are being created!

In other words, the problem is not that the Windows symlink/junction is not working: the problem is with the fact that the symlink/junction is referring to another drive.
I remember that there are two, even three ways to create a drive in Windows (a drive mapping, a subst (?) and another one(???), this is all very blurry in my head), and I'm wondering whether the symlink/junction story might be working on one kind of drive, but not the other, and if there is a way to work around this.

**Edit3 after the answer of [u1686_gravity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/u1686-grawity):**
Even when using UNC path and having the "correct" configured behaviour, it still seems not to work:

```
fsutil behavior query symlinkEvaluation
Local to local symbolic links are enabled.
Local to remote symbolic links are enabled. => That's the one, isn't it?
Remote to local symbolic links are disabled.
Remote to remote symbolic links are disabled.
```

```
C:\<Runtime_Dir>mklink /D Logs \\petrvs01\Log\TestLog\
symbolic link created for Logs <<===>> \\petrvs01\Log\TestLog\
```

The link gets created, but no logfiles are being created over there.

So, as I think I'm the right track here, I decided to perform another test: use the Windows explorer to enter the `Logs` directory/symlink/junction and create a simple text file, using the explorer's context menu. This does not work because of the following error message:

[image]

I have learned three things up to now:

1. For creating a symlink on Windows, use `mklink` instead of WSL's `ln -s`. Open a command prompt as an administrator for this.
2. For creating a symlink/junction to a remote directory, you need to use the UNC path, not the drive letter.
3. Permission for creating symlinks/junctions from and to remote directories is checked, using the `fsutil` command `fsutil behavior query symlinkEvaluation`.

Next thing I need to learn: where to check for the symlink/junction destination permissions? Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Windows has its own symlinks. Use the mklink /d command. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink

Comment: @DavidMarshall, if that works for Dominique, you might expand that to an answer, helpful to others, too. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I'm not sure that this is a duplicate - the linked post doesn't explain why WSL symlinks are unusable on Windows.

Comment: *writing logs to a directory, which is hardcoded "Logs"* - is there any chance of having a config file which says where the log directory is? Hardcoding anything like that is not a good idea, as it appears you have just found. Normally, Windows does not allow writing into the program files directory as a security measure; there are other locations intended for program data and user-specific data.

Answer (score 5):

Symlinks on Linux are implemented differently than on Windows:

- On Windows a symlink is a file-table entry that's implemented
  and manipulated by kernel calls
- On Linux, a symlink is simply a text file with a special flag,
  whose content is a path to the destination.
  (The path doesn’t even have to be valid.)

This means that symbolic links (or symlinks) created through
the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) can’t be followed by Windows.

Windows creates symlinks using the
[mklink command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink).

For more information see the article
[The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).

---

For the problem of "Access Denied", I quote from the post
[creating symbolic links on networked drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1017653/creating-symbolic-links-on-networked-drive)
part of the
[answer by GambleNerd](https://superuser.com/a/1017659/8672):

> **Access Denied Fix**
>
> If you run the `mklink /D` command as administrator and the `Link`
> part of the command is a UNC network path and you get `Access Denied`
> error message, then follow the below to potentially resolve this
> issue.
>
> 1. On there server where *(and/or on the Windows client PC you're getting the Access Denied error message when you run the command)* the
>    `Link` part of the command is located, run this command as
>    administrator on the server: `fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation`
> 2. If you see `Remote to remote symbolic links are disabled.` then run this command: `fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation R2R:1`
>
> - You can run this from the location where you're running the MKLINK command and getting access denied whether on the Windows Server itself
>   or the Windows client PC
>
> 3. Now try running your command again and hopefully it works successfully now.
>
> **Link Reference:** [Access is denied on mklink](https://superuser.com/questions/449400/access-is-denied-on-mklink)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I had completely forgotten about the Windows `mklink` command. Nevertheless it seems not to be working, as I described in the edit of my question.

Comment: Some experiments further, I can confirm that `mklink` is working for referring to another directory on the same computer (drive), but I'm trying to create such a symlink/junction to a directory on another computer. Is this possible?

Comment: @Dominique: See [Creating a symbolic link to mapped network drive in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/210824/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-mapped-network-drive-in-windows).

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks for the link, but this link covers all issues, solved by now, except the last error message `Destination folder Access Denied`. I do believe that this is even out of the scope of the symlink/junction creation and handling, but it is crucial to solve the last issues of my problem.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I clarified the text : Linux symlinks are dependent on the text-contents of the link file and a flag in the file-directory. Windows symlinks have their pointers inside the file-table, not inside a file that is user-modifiable, and require kernel primitives to change. This makes Windows symlinks harder to get wrong. Hopefully my meaning is now clearer.

Comment: @Dominique: See [Access Denied Fix](https://superuser.com/a/1017659/8672). Check also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1516507/8672).

Comment: @harrymc: you leave me with a big problem: you gave me good start, your colleague `u1686_gravity` followed up upon it and now you gave the final shot into the goal. Whose answer should I accept now? :-)

Comment: @Dominique: First, let me know which link was the final fix and I'll add it to my answer. Usually the final fix is chosen, but it's your choice.

Comment: It was the "Access Denied Fix" link, containing the `fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation R2R:1` command.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to use Linux-like symlinks on a Windows computer, referring to a location on another computer?

It's possible, but you need to use UNC paths rather than drive letters, as the latter are not nec­es­sar­i­ly global – while physical volumes have global assignments, each logon session can have its own private mappings on top of that (e.g. user 1 can have Y:\ representing one location and user 2 can have it representing another). Think of it a bit like each user having their own "mount name­space" on Linux (pam_namespace).

Specifically, all "mapped network share" drive letters are private to your logon session and will not be understood in the kernel context when the symlink is followed. So if the target is on another machine, you need to use the raw UNC path for it:

```
cmd /c mklink /d Logs \\FileServer\Trash\Logs
```

You should also make sure that local-to-remote symlink evaluation hasn't been disabled through `fsutil behavior query symlinkEvaluation`.

> where to check for the symlink/junction destination permissions? Does anybody have an idea?

Run `icacls` on the target – or right-click it in Explorer and go "Properties > Security".

```
icacls \\FileServer\Trash\Logs
```

Also, symlinks and junctions on Windows *can* have their own permissions, which can be checked using `icacls Logs /l`. I doubt that would be the problem, as the link would initially inherit the same permissions as a normal directory would – but it might be worth checking.

So first make sure file/folder creation works *without* symlinks being involved, i.e. directly through the UNC path (or a mapped drive, no difference), and only after you have that working, attempt to do the same through a symlink.

Don't forget that if your application is running as a service, with its own credentials (service account), then permissions must be granted to that account; if it's running as "NetworkService", then permissions must be granted to the *machine* account (FOOBAR$). (And if it's running as "LocalService", it will never have network share access.)

Comment: Thanks. Great answer! However although everything seems to be ok, the logs still are not created, but in fact, while trying to create a simple file in that directory, even that does not work. I've edited my question accordingly, adding a general summary of the progress until now.

Comment: in PowerShell you don't need to run cmd to create a symlink, just use `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink` [How do you create a new symlink in windows 10 using powershell (not mklink.exe)?](https://superuser.com/q/1307360/241386)

Comment: @phuclv: It's a habit due to PowerShell 5's inability to create _relative_ symlinks, which I want more often than not. (Especially when I was still setting things up and didn't have PS7 installed yet.)